# AES Key generation (C#)

Tags: c#, encryption, key, aes

i'm working on this project that uses AES encryption. The encryption / decryption part is all done, but I can't get the random AES key generator to work.. I tried multiple things, but I can't get them to work.. Help would be appreciated

Regards,
CmplDev

Comment: Can you add the code you've tried already and didn't work to your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a random string or numbers.
Following function modified [from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649202.aspx) return a random key in a specific length:

> ```
> private static string CreateSalt(int size)
> {
>     //Generate a cryptographic random number.
>     using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
>     {
>         byte[] buff = new byte[size];
>         rng.GetBytes(buff);
>
>         // Return a Base64 string representation of the random number.
>         return Convert.ToBase64String(buff);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Okay okay, I don't understand how that could be used for a AES key though.. I am still learning how the whole AES encryption works

Comment: In that case, you'll see [link](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf)

Comment: Oh, it seems to be working! I thought it would have to be something like "341BD2F53BB46681CE42ADA6BD576FF7C8628B5A01FB594E4314E0F01E2EF311"! Thanks!

Comment: [Plagiarism](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) is [not cool](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/plagiarism-should-be-addressed-specifically-in-the-faq/134715#134715). When you copy text or code from somewhere, you MUST cite your source, and you MUST clearly mark what you copied as such (use blockquote markup).